# My function isn't returning the right type, is it possible?

Tags: typescript

I am currently working on filtering a labelled enumeration and my function isn't returning the right type. I don't know why.

```
function fromNameLabels<T extends string>(src: Array<[T, string]>): 
Array<LabelledEnum<T>> {
    return src.map(([name, label]) => ({ name, label }))
}  

function fromLabelledEnum<T extends string>(src: 
Array<LabelledEnum<T>>): { [K in T]: K } {
    return src.reduce((res, {name, label}) => {
        res[name] = name
        return res
    }, Object.create(null))
}  

type Mandant = 'REN' | 'COVEA'
type TabEnum =  Array<LabelledEnum<string>>
type MapTabEnum = Record<Mandant,TabEnum>

function getTabEnumByMandant ( mandant: Mandant) {
    return TypeRendezVousValuesMap[mandant]
}

export const TypeRendezVousValuesREN = fromNameLabels([
    ["Site","Sur site"],
    ["Visio","En visio"],
    ["Telephonique","Par téléphone"],
    ["RdvGalant","Rendez vous galant"],
    ["RdvSport","rendez vous sportif"],
    ["MatchSquash","match de squash"],
])

export const TypeRendezVousValuesCOVEA = fromNameLabels([
    ["RdvGalant","Rendez vous galant"],
    ["RdvSport","rendez vous sportif"],
    ["MatchSquash","match de squash"],
])

export const TypeRendezVousValuesMap: MapTabEnum = {
    'REN':TypeRendezVousValuesREN,
    'COVEA':TypeRendezVousValuesCOVEA
}

export const TypeRendezVousCovea = fromLabelledEnum(getTabEnumByMandant ('COVEA'))
export type TypeRendezVous = keyof typeof TypeRendezVousCovea
```

What i want is for my TypeRendezVousCovea of this type :

```
const TypeReference: {
    ReferenceSinistre: "ReferenceSinistre";
    NumeroContrat: "NumeroContrat";
    Autre: "Autre";
}
```

But actually it is this type :

```
const TypeRendezVousCovea: {
    [x: string]: string;
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas or if it is possible at all?
I'm using version 3.0.1 of typescript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some small issues that cause the problem. The first one is that `getTabEnumByMandant` need a generic type parameter to capture that actual value passed in in order to return the exact type of the key in `TypeRendezVousValuesMap`.

Also since you type `TypeRendezVousValuesMap` explicitly, the actual type of the object literal  is lost. If we remove the annotation it will keep the type. If you want to constrain `TypeRendezVousValuesMap` you can use a generic function (as I did below)

```
type LabelledEnum<T> = { name: T, label: string }
function fromNameLabels<T extends string>(src: Array<[T, string]>): Array<LabelledEnum<T>> {
  return src.map(([name, label]) => ({ name, label }))
}

function fromLabelledEnum<T extends string>(src: Array<LabelledEnum<T>>): { [K in T]: K } {
  return src.reduce((res, { name, label }) => {
    res[name] = name
    return res
  }, Object.create(null))
}

type Mandant = 'REN' | 'COVEA'
type TabEnum = Array<LabelledEnum<string>>
type MapTabEnum = Record<Mandant, TabEnum>

function getTabEnumByMandant<K extends Mandant>(mandant: K) {
  return TypeRendezVousValuesMap[mandant]
}

export const TypeRendezVousValuesREN = fromNameLabels([
  ["Site", "Sur site"],
  ["Visio", "En visio"],
  ["Telephonique", "Par téléphone"],
  ["RdvGalant", "Rendez vous galant"],
  ["RdvSport", "rendez vous sportif"],
  ["MatchSquash", "match de squash"],
])

export const TypeRendezVousValuesCOVEA = fromNameLabels([
  ["RdvGalant", "Rendez vous galant"],
  ["RdvSport", "rendez vous sportif"],
  ["MatchSquash", "match de squash"],
])

export const TypeRendezVousValuesMap = (<T extends MapTabEnum>(o: T) => o)({
  'REN': TypeRendezVousValuesREN,
  'COVEA': TypeRendezVousValuesCOVEA
})

export const TypeRendezVousCovea = fromLabelledEnum(getTabEnumByMandant('COVEA'))
// const TypeRendezVousCovea: {
//   RdvGalant: "RdvGalant";
//   RdvSport: "RdvSport";
//   MatchSquash: "MatchSquash";
// }
```

Comment: Great answer Titian !